# How to test a database connection?

Tags: database, forms

I'm writing a module that will have to make a connection to a seperate database. In order for the user to configure the database, I'm allowing the user to fill out the database connection info in the module configuration form.

How can I test the database connection before submitting the form?

I added the relevant code below:

```
function mymodule_form($form, &$form_state) {
  //Form code omitted
  $form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_form_submit';
  $form = system_settings_form($form);
  return $form;
}

function mymodule_form_validate($form, &$form_state){
  // Validation code, test db connection, need help here.
}

function mymodule_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $values = $form_state['values'];
  $database = array(
    'database' => $values['database_name'],
    'username' => $values['database_username'],
    'password' => $values['database_password'],
    'host' => $values['database_host'],
    'driver' => $values['database_driver'],
  );
  Database::addConnectionInfo('mymoduleDB', 'default', $database);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything in [`Database`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/class/Database/7) or [`DatabaseConnection`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/class/DatabaseConnection/7) specifically. In a pinch you can just run a query that you know won't throw an exception in a Drupal site:

```
try {
  db_set_active('mymoduleDB');
  db_query('SELECT COUNT(nid) FROM {node}');
}
catch (\PDOException $e) {
  // Berate the user.
}
// PHP5.5+ only
finally {
  db_set_active('default');
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't I need to use another connection key for testing?

Comment: That's what `db_set_active` is for unless I've misunderstood what you mean?

Comment: Nevermind, i got it working. Thanks for the help, marked as correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Before I give you this potential solution this:  Passing db info around unencrypted seems like a bad idea.  other people may have a better idea of how to do this more securely.

Using [hook_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7), you can create a function that accepts arguments via POST data.

Attach Javascript with your AJAX event using the [forms API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attached).